# Kendo button `k-danger` not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo MVC in C# project.

I am trying to add `k-danger` class to kendo button. I don't know why but it's not working where `k-primary` class works.

This is my buttons code:

```
<button type='button' id='Button1' onclick='Delete(#=ID#)' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add k-danger'>  // This is just showing the default button
    <span class='k-icon k-i-trash'></span> 
</button>

<button type='button' id='Button2' onclick='Info(#=ID#)' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add k-i-pencil'>  // This is showing the primary button
    <span class='k-icon k-i-pencil'></span> 
</button>
```

The icons works perfectly.
I searched everywhere but I found nothing about this. So I am concluding that there is no `k-danger` class, I don't know if I am wrong.

If no `k-danger` is available is there anything else I can use instead of `k-danger`?

I can provide full code if it's needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`danger` (or actually `btn-danger`) is a Bootstrap-specific CSS class name and indeed, it does not exist in the Kendo UI stylesheet. There are two options that I would suggest:

1. Assuming that you have the Bootstrap stylesheet registered, try using the `btn-danger` CSS class of Bootstrap. The downside is that you will likely stumble upon Kendo UI vs Bootstrap style conflicts and the resulting button appearance will be a mix between the two libraries' styles.
2. Create your own Kendo UI "danger" button styling. For example, add the following CSS rule to a stylesheet, which is registered after the Kendo UI stylesheet:

   ```
   .k-button.k-danger,
   .k-button.k-danger:active {
       background-color: #f00;
       color: #fff;
       border-color: #f00;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
k-danger does not have any style in kendo css,
```

You need to create your custom style to get your result or just add bootstrap css and add "btn btn-danger" class in you Danger Button.

Check this JsBin Demo

[Js Bin Example](https://jsbin.com/ceruqek/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

By default kendo provide you with `k-error-colored` as [shown here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styling/panels).

The other handy classes are :

- `k-info-colored`
- `k-success-colored`
- `k-warning-colored`

You just have to use it with `k-button`

[This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m9nLusnb/1/) shows how it render.

[image]